# GWT screen loads in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, gwt, gxt

We added a new screen to our web application, which is implemented in Java using [GWT](https://www.gwtproject.org/) 2.8.2 and [GXT](https://www.sencha.com/products/gxt/) 4.0.2. The screen loads fine in Firefox 119.0.1, but in Chrome 119.0.6045.124 the portion of the screen that is implemented by the new Java class is blank for some reason. I did a "View Source" in both Firefox and Chrome, and the HTML returned by both browsers is exactly the same, so there must be some Javascript that is failing to load the screen in Chrome. But the Chrome developer tools console shows no errors.

I tried upgrading to GWT 2.9.0 and 2.10.0, and that did not fix the problem. Any suggestions for how I can troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: See [here](https://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling.html#Can_I_speed_up_the_GWT_compiler?) - maybe you have `UserAgent` set to only compile for Firefox.

Comment: It is set to compile for both Firefox and Chrome.